# Java Console Game Development | Methods

Tags: java

Alright, allow me to elaborate on my dilemma.

I'm making a Console Game with Java. It's not going to be super simple, but I don't want it to be really advanced either. I'm just trying to test my skills using the basics that I've learned. I've started a few times, but constantly ran into the same "problem".

It's not exactly a problem though, just something I could do better. The best way to explain it is to just show some example code.

Here is my Main class. We'll call it "Main.java".

```
package com.mattkx4.cgamedev.main;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Ok, now let's make a new method in our Main.java. We'll call this method "Start". Our Main class now looks like so:

```
package com.mattkx4.cgamedev.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public static void start() {
        System.out.println("This is the start.");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter \"NEXT\" to continue.");
        String in = s.nextLine();

        if(in.equalsIgnoreCase("NEXT")) {
        }else{
            System.out.println("Please input \"NEXT\".");
            start();
        }
    }
}
```

Now we'll add two more methods. We'll call them "middle" and "end". Our finished class now looks like so:

```
package com.mattkx4.cgamedev.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        start();
    }

    public static void start() {
        System.out.println("This is the start.");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter \"NEXT\" to continue.");
        String in = s.nextLine();

        if(in.equalsIgnoreCase("NEXT")) {
            middle();
            s.close();
            System.exit(0);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Please input \"NEXT\".");
            start();
        }
    }

    public static void middle() {
        System.out.println("This is the middle.");
        System.out.println("Let's move on to the end.");
        end();
    }

    public static void end() {
        System.out.println("This is the end.\nFinishing up, and heading back to the start() method to close program.");
    }
}
```

What I've written here is in my opinion a very inefficient program. Inefficient to code with that is. There's has to be another way to doing this program, rather than calling methods inside of other methods to move along the program.

A summary of my question: Is the above code the most efficient way to write a console game?

Thanks in advance! If you have any questions I'll be happy to answer them.
-Matthew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many kinds of answers to your question.  I'll just enumerate some basic things.

1. Your design is linear and completely rigid.  Unflexible.  Most applications like this, rather than chaining any methods or the like, store a *state* somehow.  This is often achieved with an `enum`.  It's important to understand how [state-based programming works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata-based_programming).  So you might have something like:

   ```
   public enum GameState {
       LOAD, START, STOP, BEGIN, MIDDLE, END, GAME_OVER // ... and so on
   }
   ```
2. You're using a bunch of `static` methods.  This is certainly not what you want to do.  It completely abandons any object-orientation.  If you're making a game world, you will, ideally, have a class for every distinct object in your world, and they will be arranged in a logical hierarchy, by `extends`-ing each other or `implements`-ing different interfaces.
3. You will need to learn concurrency.  Your user input will almost necessarily come asynchronously to the rendering of your game, if it has any sophistication at all.  At the very, *very* least, you'll probably at least need [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) to create a GUI.

So, just with those three very basic notes, you will need to study up on [object-orientation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/), [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html), [concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), and all the various data structures available to you.  Your example, to be frank, has the sophistication of a Java 101 project.  (I'm not saying that to be mean.)  If you plan to make a real game, you'll need a lot more of the basics under your belt before you can make real headway.

It's good that you're thinking big, and it's good that your goals for programming are big.  But break that big dream up into manageable chunks.  It will get your farther, faster, and it will also prevent you from getting discouraged.

Best of luck to you!

---

As a side note, if you start coding up some simple games (even something as simple as a console-based Hangman or Tic-Tac-Toe), please come around to the [Code Review Beta](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  We'll be more than happy to give you a detailed review of your code and help you along the path to becoming a veteran programmer!  It's a good community with a lot of very constructive criticism.  I've both helped people there (with Java) and received a good amount of help as I learned Python.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer! I'll study very hard on those three subjects until I'm comfortable with them! This question was asked to find a better way of making a game. Rather than the "linear" and "unflexible" programming I've been doing. Thank you!

Comment: @Mattkx4 I look forward to buying your indie game on Steam some day! :)

Comment: Good answer Jeff.  Just a few quick notes to OP, the answer by Victor describes a pretty solid technique (having a main game loop) to implement the items Jeff has described.  Also, the concept described in item 2 is polymorphism; polymorphism is a great way to leave the door open for code expansion in the future in any programming. Lastly, there is an incomplete (yet very informative) Java game engine [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8CAB66181A502179) by DesignsbyZephyr that you may want to investigate.

Comment: @user3507600 Thanks for pointing out the Game Loop answer.  Another good technique to have under your belt, especially at the beginning.

Comment: @JeffGohlke Thanks for the great answers and support!

Comment: @user3507600 Funny you brought up that YouTube series :) I was following that tutorial, but I happened to Wipe my Win8 and install a different OS so I lost all my progress. I'll definitely refer back to that!

Comment: @Mattkx4, if you've already gone through it, probably no reason to go watch it again (the code is on [github](https://github.com/vanZeben/2D-Game-Engine)).

Comment: @user3507600 I only got to ep 6 or 7.... And I stole the sprite sheet from github so I didn't have to do the textures myself :)

Comment: @JeffGohlke I went through and really studied the docs on OOP, and I've really learned a lot! Before when I programmed in Java everything was in the braces that followed the class declaration! Now I know that not everything is a class! Now I know what Interfaces, Objects, Classes, and much more is! Thanks for giving me the push to look harder :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't quite get what this has to do with performance or optimization. But normally you use classes and methods to structure your program.

That being said, there is a huge mistake in your `start` method. You should axoid the unnecessary recursion and use a loop instead, and remove the `exit` call:

```
public static void start() {
    System.out.println("This is the start.");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter \"NEXT\" to continue.");
    String in = s.nextLine();

    if(in.equalsIgnoreCase("NEXT")) {
        middle();
        s.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Please input \"NEXT\".");
        start();  // <-- recursion!
    }
}
```

Better do it like this:

```
public static void start() {
    System.out.println("This is the start.");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter \"NEXT\" to continue.");

    while ( !s.nextLine().equals("NEXT")) {
        System.out.println("Please input \"NEXT\".");
    }

    middle();

    // you probably also want to put "end();" here - it is not called in the original code
    s.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can see now there are many different ways of designing this type of game! I will also remember your use of the while loop with the scanner checking :) That could be very useful.

Answer (score 3):

I guess what you are trying to build up is an main skeleton of the application. I suggest to search for "Game Loop". There a lots of good articles down there about that.

For a general solution, the algorithm is, at big scales, more or less like this:

```
while (notExit()) {
   event = getNextEvent(); // this can be the user keyboard input or mouse
   renderGame(); // display the graphics on the screen
   doGameLogic(event); // do the game logic according to the events occurred
}
```

Later, you must take into account how many times per seconds you draw on the screen (FPS) and how many times you compute changes (Physic Frames per second).

Any analogy to the GUI programming is just pure coincidence. I was joking, it is not coincidence, is a fact that GUI and Game Programming shared a thread that fulfill the role of event dispatch thread.

For more information i suggest to read this tutorials : http://sol.gfxile.net/gp/index.html.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the ideas! I appreciate your consideration!

Comment: Of nothing!! Best of the luck mate!!

Answer (score 2):

It *really* depends on the type of application/game how you want to structure it.

In this case, you may find it useful to have some kind of control method which runs the functions in the correct order and has your "flow" logic.

In a more complicated game this method would deal with user input that directs them to different rooms/levels/etc. And you may even have smaller control methods that deal with sub parts.

For instance,
You could have a playGame method that calls registerPlayer(), which would process getting the player's name and any other information. When that method returns then playGame would call a levelOne() method and so on and so forth.

Just try to break it up into logical units for your game!

Comment: I understand the second part of your answer with the sub parts and so on. Where if you have the method getUserInfo() for example, you would run the getName(), getAge(), and getGender(), inside that method (Theoretic methods of course), but you mentioned a control method in the second paragraph. Can you explain in a little more detail what you mean? -Matthew

Comment: I guess the best way to explain what I mean is lets say you have a basic text based game where you can enter north, south, east, or west. Your "control method" would be what I called playGame and would deal with getting user input validating it, and then directing the flow of the program to the appropriate method based on the user input

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification! Accepting your answer now, as it definitely answered my question! EDIT: Actually, I'm too much of a noob to answer your question soooo, when I get that I high I will :)

Comment: I realize this is more advanced, but most games handle this as a Finite State Machine.

Answer (score 2):

solution from top of my head,

create class

```
class Location{
public Location( String locationId, String desctiption, List<String> exit){
//populate fields
}

private final String locationId;
private final String desctiption;
private final List<String> exits;
//getters ommited
}
```

then you could have 3 locations;

```
start = new Location("START","This is the start.",Arrays.asList("middle"));
middle= new Location("middle","This is the middle.\nLet's move on to the end.",Arrays.asList("end"));
end= new Location("end","This is the end.",null);
```

now your launcher class

public class Game {
    Map locations = new HashMap();

```
public Game() {
    locations.put("START", new Location("START", "This is the start.",
            Arrays.asList("middle")));
    locations.put("middle",
            new Location("middle",
                    "This is the middle.\nLet's move on to the end.",
                    Arrays.asList("end")));
    locations.put("end", new Location("end", "This is the end.", null));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.start();

}

private void start() {
    visitLocation(locations.get("START"));

}

public void visitLocation(Location location) {
    System.out.println(location.getDescription());

    if (location.getExits().isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String in = "";
    do {
        System.out.println("Choose exit from location : ");
        for (String exit : location.getExits())
            System.out.print(exit + " ");
        in = s.nextLine();
    } while (!location.getExits().contains(in));
    s.close();

    visitLocation(locations.get(in));
}
```

}

this is still not best but i think it will give you some ideas,

Comment: Yup definitely getting some ideas! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mattkx4 basic concept behind this, was to create your location/states object and transitions between them, and then depends on input change state,

Comment: Yes, that's what I got out of this code! I will definitely use this!